# Best way of using broadcast receiver to receive long processes sms

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am new on Android and this is my first app.

I have an app that receive  a formatted sms and i am using a BroadcastReceiver to listen for an incoming messages.

Inside onReceive I have a process where it will check for a duplicate record in the database.
(database have 500K+ rows) And save it, if there is no duplicate.

is it correct or i have to use some handler to handle the process? Because if there are incoming messages the app has a delayed response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to get a thread executor service, and submit `Runnable` tasks to it.

```
//--dedicated thread to run tasks one after another--
private final ExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

//--handle incoming sms--
public void handleSms(final String input, final SQLiteDatabase db){
    s.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //--do stuff with input and db
        }
    });
}
```